# How can I pass string value for “asp-for” in .Net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to create a generic view, but I'm having a problem with asp-for accepting string input from a variable.

The problem I'm having is very similar to this: [How can I pass string value for "asp-for" in asp net 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34282640/how-can-i-pass-string-value-for-asp-for-in-asp-net-5)

However, the answer provided in that ticket does not work in .Net Core.

Here is a sample from the razor page:

```
@foreach (var property in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)
{
    var propertyName = property.DisplayName ?? property.PropertyName;

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="@propertyName" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="@propertyName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@propertyName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

Above I'm trying to create a input field, input name and validation for each property of a object.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is only possible with `Html.Label()` and such. Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58130119/332528

So in your case it would be:

```
@foreach (var property in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)
{
    var propertyName = property.DisplayName ?? property.PropertyName;

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label(propertyName, null, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.Editor(propertyName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessage(item, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "text-danger" } })
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

I know it sucks but there seems to be no better way... Seems like in Razor if you make half a step sidewards everything gets completely broken. I can't help but compare it to JSX where mixing JS and HTML just works without any surprises or magic syntax. I wish we had something like that for C#...