# How to use asp-for TagHelper combined with Reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have a class *Foo* which contains a lot of properties, I'd like to iterate through all of them into a form. The website is built using ASP.NET Core 2.2 and Razor.

How can I build a MemberExpression that asp-for TagHelper seems to expect using Reflection? I've read a couple of post about this on the Forum but none of the answer fits my need.

The following snippet doesn't work.

```
@model Foo;
<h1>Foo Reflective filling example</h1>

    @foreach(var property in typeof(Foo).GetProperties()) {
        <p>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label asp-for="@property.Name"></label> @*doesn't work!'*@
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input asp-for="@property.Name" class="form-control" id="property.Name"/>
                    <span asp-validation-for="@property.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </p>
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you create(and fill) instance from Foo class?

Comment: Foo instance is passed via a view model. I'll update the example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The InputTagHelper helps us to write code in a style of **declarative** programming. When you find it difficult to render different fields dynamically by reflection, feel free to use the **`@Html.Xyz` equivalent** in a **programmatic** way.

Your code can be rewritten as below:

```
@foreach(var property in typeof(Foo).GetProperties()) {
    <p>
        <div class="row" >
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.Label(@property.Name)
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.Editor(@property.Name,  new { htmlAttributes = new{ @class="form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessage(@property.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class="text-danger"} })
            </div>
        </div>
    </p>
}
```

### Demo :

I create a custom Foo DTO as below :

```
public class Foo{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Address {get;set;}
    public DateTime UpdatedAt{get;set;}
}
```

And the rendered form is :

[image]

Comment: This worked, thanks, I didn't know that it was equivalent. But, I still face an issue (that I didn't expose in my question), how can I enumerate and fill fields from a child object *NestedFoo* ? The nested object is taken into account correctly when I enumerate all properties from *Foo*, but what would be the syntax if I want to ONLY get properties from the child object by reflection? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @XavierAM That can be done by using a partial view recursively :）

Comment: I don't know if this will render form objects that I can actually use, but it the code WORKS right out of the box. Thanks for giving me something comprehensible that actually works. Most of these reflection examples that generate code don't work at all. This gets me started.

Answer (score 0):

> Right click to solution --> Add --> New Folder(Models)
>
> Right click to Models folder --> Add --> Class(Foo)

Foo class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
}
```

Index.cshtml file:

```
@foreach (var property in typeof(YourProjectName.Models.Foo).GetProperties())
{
    <p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label asp-for="@property.Name"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input asp-for="@property.Name" class="form-control" id="property.Name" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@property.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </p>
}
```

Result:

```
<body>
    <p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label asp-for="A"></label> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input class="form-control" id="property.Name" asp-for="A">
                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="A"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    <p></p>
    <p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label asp-for="B"></label> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input class="form-control" id="property.Name" asp-for="B">
                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="B"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    <p></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Hmm. This does not work for me... I get : 

<input class="form-control" id="*property.Name*" type="text" name="*property.Name*" value="PropertyName">

And the label only writes *Name*

Comment: What do you mean by *adding Foo.cs to the model folder* ?

Comment: https://www.imagevisit.com/image/bDQE1 you have to add new folder (Models) your solution and add new class (Foo) to Models folder.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the problem. Moving a class from a folder to another never changed a *reference* to this class.

Comment: Share your problem example on github and type link here please.

Comment: This is not possible.