# HtmlHelper to render nested Tag Helpers in MVC 6 vNext

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

***Q:*** Is there a way to render the output of tag helpers using an IHtmlHelper extension?

***Info:*** I'm using ASP.NET 5 / MVC 6 (vNext) to render the following in a View:

```
<cache expires-after="@TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)">
    <div custom-tag-helper-parm="9289"></div>        
</cache>
```

I now have a HtmlHelper extension method to write this bit of HTML:

```
public static HtmlString RenderPortalContent(this IHtmlHelper HtmlHelper, string customTagHelperParm)
{              
        var output = $@"<cache expires-after='{@TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)}'>
                            <div custom-tag-helper-parm = '{customTagHelperParm}'>
                            </div>
                        </cache>";      

        return new HtmlString(output);
}
```

Currently, as would be expected, that HTML is output literally.  In other words, neither the `<cache>` nor the `custom-tag-helper-parm` TagHelpers are processed.

***Is there a way to render the output of tag helpers using an IHtmlHelper extension like this?***

Comment: What do you exactly want to achieve? Specifically, what do you want to do with "customTagHelperParm"? How do you plan to call this helper?

Comment: You could create your own tag helper that renders nested tag helpers, instead of an html helper that renders nested tag helpers. For example see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32692857/nesting-taghelpers-in-asp-net-5-mvc-6/32695324#32695324)

Comment: Did you eventually figured out a way to do this? Currently I think that building a custom taghelper is the only way to achieve what I want.

Comment: No, I was never able to figure out a solution and just ended up working around it.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you want to do something like

```
@Html.RenderPortalContent("blah")
```

in your view. If so, you can do something like this:

```cs
public static HtmlString RenderPortalContent(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, string parameter)
{
    var cache = new TagBuilder("cache");
    cache.Attributes.Add("expires-after", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).Seconds.ToString());
    var div = new TagBuilder("div");
    div.Attributes.Add("custom-tag-helper-parm", parameter);

    cache.InnerHtml.Append(div);

    var writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    cache.WriteTo(writer, new HtmlEncoder());
    return new HtmlString(writer.ToString());
}
```

**However**, if you want to extend your tag to allow inner tags and more flexibility, you actually need to write your own TagHelper. Luckily, these aren't too difficult to write.

---

**Edit:** Have you tried using [ViewComponents](http://docs.asp.net/projects/mvc/en/latest/views/view-components.html)?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this still seems to render the built HTML literally.  I.e. i get an actual "<cache>" element in the final HTML.  If I had put that "<cache>" element directly into the View file, it would have been processed and replaced with what's in the memory cache for the given key.