# Use TagHelper inside another TagHelper

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have build a custom tag helper that dynamicaly build a form with input tags.

Example

```
foreach(var foo in foos)
{
htmlOutput += $"<input asp-for='{foo.FieldName}' />";
}
```

then i want to model bind this, but my custom tag helper output the asp-for attribute instead of model bind it, probably because im trying to use a tag helper inside my custom tag helper. Any way to get around this?

Comment: You can nest them as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32692857/nesting-taghelpers-in-asp-net-5-mvc-6) but I dont think you can add them from within the TagHelper `Process` method