# Instantiating and Invoking TagHelpers Manually

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

This is a follow up question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42010429/can-i-use-a-tag-helper-in-a-custom-tag-helper-that-returns-html), which seems to be for an older ASP.NET Core version (I'm using 2.1).

I'm trying to call a TagHelper manually from within a TagHelper. Applying the Answer in the linked question above, the TagHelper.Process looks like so:

```
public override async void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
    var anchorTagHelper = new AnchorTagHelper
    {
        Action = "Home",
    };
    var anchorOutput = new TagHelperOutput("a", new TagHelperAttributeList(), (useCachedResult, encoder) => new HtmlString());
    var anchorContext = new TagHelperContext(
        new TagHelperAttributeList(new[] { new TagHelperAttribute("asp-action", new HtmlString("Home")) }),
        new Dictionary<object, object>(),
        Guid.NewGuid());
    await anchorTagHelper.ProcessAsync(anchorContext, anchorOutput);
    output.Content.SetHtmlContent(anchorOutput);
}
```

Several compiler errors occur at this point.

> cannot convert from 'System.Guid' to 'string'

No problem, I can cast to a String.

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
>   parameter 'value' of 'HtmlString.HtmlString(string)

Checking the MSDN page for the [TagHelperOutput constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.taghelpers.taghelperoutput.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Razor_TagHelpers_TagHelperOutput__ctor_System_String_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Razor_TagHelpers_TagHelperAttributeList_System_Func_System_Boolean_System_Text_Encodings_Web_HtmlEncoder_System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Razor_TagHelpers_TagHelperContent___), it seems it doesn't take an `HtmlString` anymore.

I changed that argument to a delegate fuction:

```
new TagHelperOutput("a", new TagHelperAttributeList(),
    (useCachedResult, encoder) => Task.Factory.StartNew<TagHelperContent>(
         () => new DefaultTagHelperContent()));
```

The last compiler error:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
>   parameter 'generator' of
>   'AnchorTagHelper.AnchorTagHelper(IHtmlGenerator)

Hoping its an optional parameter, I passed in null:

```
var anchorTagHelper = new AnchorTagHelper(null);
```

---

It finally compiled - but this led to a null pointer exception on runtime:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.InputTagHelper.Process(TagHelperContext
>   context, TagHelperOutput output)

My question is thus: how can I instantiate [`AnchorTagHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.taghelpers.anchortaghelper.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_TagHelpers_AnchorTagHelper__ctor_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ViewFeatures_IHtmlGenerator_) so I can manually invoke TagHelpers in C#?

**EDIT**: I've DI'd IHtmlGenerator and got a more meaningful error message:

```
private IHtmlGenerator htmlGenerator;
public myAnchorTagHelper(IHtmlGenerator htmlGenerator) {
    this.htmlGenerator = htmlGenerator;
}
```

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: viewContext>
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.DefaultHtmlGenerator.GenerateActionLink(ViewContext
>   viewContext, String linkText, String actionName, String
>   controllerName, String protocol, String hostname, String fragment,
>   Object routeValues, Object htmlAttributes)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.AnchorTagHelper.Process(TagHelperContext
>   context, TagHelperOutput output)    at
>   EAGLEweb2020.Models.EAGLEinputTagHelper.Process(TagHelperContext
>   context, TagHelperOutput output) in
>   C:\Users\1135937\source\repos\EAGLEweb2020\EAGLEweb2020\Models\TagHelpers\EAGLEinputTagHelper.cs:line
>   66    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext
>   context, TagHelperOutput output)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.d__0.MoveNext()

But how can I DI a ViewContext?

**EDIT 2:**

Turns out ViewContext is a public property in AnchorTagHelper:

```
AnchorTagHelper inputTagHelper = new AnchorTagHelper(htmlGenerator);
inputTagHelper.ViewContext = viewContext;
```

But now the content is empty...

Answer (score 1):

Hi I was going through this and you got stuck at the ViewContext and the Output.
I have done a similar project. Here's the code, hope it helps.

```
[HtmlTargetElement(ParentAnchorTag)]
public class ParentActionTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private const string ParentAnchorTag = "p-a";

    [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
    [ViewContext]
    public ViewContext viewContext { get; set; }

    private readonly IHtmlGenerator _htmlGenerator;

    public ParentActionTagHelper(IHtmlGenerator htmlGenerator)
    {
        _htmlGenerator = htmlGenerator;
    }
    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.TagName = "div";

        var anchorTagHelper = new AnchorTagHelper(_htmlGenerator)
        {
            Action = "Privacy",
            ViewContext = viewContext,

        };
        var anchorOutput = new TagHelperOutput("a", new TagHelperAttributeList(),
            (useCachedResult, encoder) =>  Task.Factory.StartNew<TagHelperContent>(
                 () => new DefaultTagHelperContent()));
        anchorOutput.Content.AppendHtml("Privacy Link");
        var anchorContext = new TagHelperContext(
            new TagHelperAttributeList(new[]
            {
                new TagHelperAttribute("asp-action", new HtmlString("Privacy"))
            }),
                new Dictionary<object, object>(),
                Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

        anchorTagHelper.ProcessAsync(anchorContext, anchorOutput).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        output.Content.SetHtmlContent(anchorOutput);
    }
}
```